# Loop that returns to starting point for selecting Nth row

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I want to select `M` companies from a sample of `S` companies and doing this starting from a random number selected between `1` and `S` and selecting every `N`th company.

To get the sample of M, I want the loop to come back to starting point for selecting the companies. Here `xInterval` is `N`, `lrowCount` is `S` and `M` is `N/S`. I tried using offset and changing indices of for loop.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
Sub circularSystematicSampling()

Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim xInterval As Integer
Dim lrowCount As Integer
Dim endPoint As Integer
Dim circular As Boolean


xTitleId = "Testing"

Set InputRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    Set InputRng = InputRng.Offset(1).Resize(InputRng.Rows.Count - 1)

    InputRng.Select

xInterval = Application.InputBox("Number of companies is" & " " & InputRng.Rows.Count & vbCrLf & " Enter row interval", xTitleId, Type:=1)
lrowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

randomStart = Int((lrowCount - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
endPoint = Int(lrowCount + randomStart)
endPoint2 = Int(randomStart - 1)


If endPoint > lrowCount Then
    circular = True
End If

For i = (1 + randomStart) To endPoint Step xInterval
    Set rng = InputRng.Cells(i, 1)

    If circular Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If


    If OutRng Is Nothing Then
        Set OutRng = rng
    Else
        Set OutRng = Application.Union(OutRng, rng)
    End If

Next
OutRng.EntireRow.Select

With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

How do I modify this loop to come back to starting point when selecting xInterval row? Thanks.

Edit: Another approach while circular true

```
If circular Then
For j = 1 To endPoint2 Step xInterval ' ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Set rng2 = InputRng.Cells(j, endPoint2)
End If

If OutRng Is Nothing Then
    Set OutRng = rng
Else
    Set OutRng = Application.Union(OutRng, rng, rng2)
End If
```

Another possibility using DO while

```
For i = (1 + randomStart) To endPoint Step xInterval
    Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Set rng = InputRng.Cells(i, endPoint)

Do While IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
For j = 1 To endPoint2 Step xInterval
Set rng2 = InputRng.Cells(j, endPoint2)
End If

If OutRng Is Nothing Then
    Set OutRng = rng
Else
    Set OutRng = Application.Union(OutRng, rng, rng2)
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just loop over the actual rows from `1` to `S` then you can use the `Mod` function to send the loop back 'to the top':

```
For lngCounter = 1 To lngRowCount Step lngRowInterval
    lngTargetRow = (lngRandRowStart + lngCounter) Mod lngRowCount
    strOutRanges = strOutRanges & rngData.Cells(lngTargetRow + 1, 1).Address & ","
Next lngCounter
```

I had an issue with your method of `Union`ing the `Range`s so am just building a list of cell addresses to format in the loop.

Full example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub circularSystematicSampling()

    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim lngRowCount As Long
    Dim lngRowInterval As Long
    Dim lngRandRowStart As Long
    Dim lngCounter As Long
    Dim lngTargetRow As Long
    Dim strOutRanges As String
    Dim rngOut As Range

    ' set range to iterate
    Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    ' drop header
    Set rngData = rngData.Offset(1).Resize(rngData.Rows.Count - 1)
    ' get total rows
    lngRowCount = rngData.Rows.Count
    ' set an interval
    lngRowInterval = Application.InputBox("Enter row interval", "Test", 1)
    ' set a random start point
    lngRandRowStart = Int(rngData.Rows.Count * Rnd + 1)

    ' iterate rows - calculate offset in loop
    strOutRanges = ""
    For lngCounter = 1 To lngRowCount Step lngRowInterval
        lngTargetRow = (lngRandRowStart + lngCounter) Mod lngRowCount
        strOutRanges = strOutRanges & rngData.Cells(lngTargetRow + 1, 1).Address & ","
    Next lngCounter
    'drop trailing comma
    strOutRanges = Left(strOutRanges, Len(strOutRanges) - 1)

    ' create range with string of addresses
    Set rngOut = Range(strOutRanges)
    Debug.Print rngOut.Address

    With rngOut.EntireRow.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robin. I was trying to apply Mod function but did not know how to specify it. The code is somehow not working and not giving any error either.  Any suggestions on debugging it?

Comment: My test data was simply column A with a header ('company') and company names A-Z in rows 2 to 27. That was it. Maybe you could try and change the `rngData` variable to reference your list of companies ? There's a line in there - `Debug.Print rngOut.Address` - that says which cells should get formatted. What does that say in your Immediate Window?

Comment: My data has Q columns with the first row as header information for variables. The data has both numbers and strings. Would change the dimension of strOutRanges help? Also what is this line doing    strOutRanges = Left(strOutRanges, Len(strOutRanges) - 1) when outputting data?

Comment: Each time a row (or cell) is identified to be highlighted, the address is added to `strOutRanges` plus a comma. That will leave the string like `a,b,c,` - so the final comma needs to be stripped off. I did it that way because I found the method with `OutRange = Union(OutRange, NewRange` didn't work in my example.

Comment: Would an example dataset help in getting the formatting right?

Comment: Yes it would :) I can adjust my example against that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138506/discussion-between-anusha-and-robin-mackenzie).

Comment: I am getting an error in `' create range with string of addresses
    Set rngOut = Range(strOutRanges)` part of the code as `Error 1004. Method Range of object _Global failed`. I want to paste these selected rows on another sheet and therefore require the object format to allow that.

Comment: Maybe you should try and adapt for your original method of using `Union` for adding the `Range`s.?

Comment: Yes, I am trying that but thought I would ask as this is more efficient code.

Comment: Pretty sure that the method of building a string and then using that string to build a non-contiguous range has a limit. If you have a big data set you are probably hitting the limit

Comment: I have adapted my code. Just for curiousity, how could this mod function can be defined so that the selection starts from that row itself rather than two rows later. Would the approach using _do while_ work for this question?

Comment: Maybe try `For lngCounter = 0 To lngRowCount Step lngRowInterval - 1` and then in the loop `strOutRanges = strOutRanges & rngData.Cells(lngTargetRow, 1).Address & ","`. Just something to try out... not sure if it will work.